# Error while creating Hybrid Mobile Application Project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I have eclipse Oxygen and have Thym and IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation plugin installed. However when I try to create a new Hybrid Mobile Application Project, I got the following error:

```
Can not retrieve plugin catalog
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen  is not supported by MobilFirst yet use Eclipse juno .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **IBM MobileFirst Studio plug-in** helps you manage your Cordova project in the Eclipse development environment. **Cordova projects** are typically managed by entering commands on the Cordova command line.

Eclipse Oxygen is not supported by MobileFirst yet.

> Supported Latest Eclipse Versions for **MobileFirst** & **Thym** plug-in:  **Neon (4.6)**

**For more information check:**

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-thym

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mobilefirst-foundation-studio#group-details

[image]

Comment: I reinstalled eclipse, but this time I used Eclipse Neon. After installing Thym and MFP Studio from marketplace, I tried to create cordova project and it has the same issue. Then I left to do something else, and after awhile I tried it again. This time it works. Do you think connections to the cordova plugin repository is the issue?

Comment: May be due to proxy / connection issue, eclipse not able to connect with plugin repository. Also that issue is releted to OKHTTP wich caused due to connection.

Comment: Recommended way to use Cordova based project is command line interface (CLI).

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the CLI